# Create Extension Method TryGetValue(TKey, out TValue) of Enumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> just like of Dictionary<TKey, TValue>

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

I have a `Enumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`. I want to create a `bool TryGetValue(TKey, out TValue)` extension method of it just like it is available in `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

I tried

```
public static bool TryGetValue<TKey, TValue>
(this Enumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> mapping, TKey key, out TValue value)
{
    bool retVal = false;

    KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> kvp;

    kvp = mapping.First(x => x.Key.Equals(key));

    if(kvp.Key == null && kvp.Value == null)
    {
        retVal = false;
        value = default(TValue);
    }
    else
    {
        retVal = true;
        value = kvp.Value;
    }

    return retval;
}
```

Is this correct way? If not please suggest one.

**Note:**

I cannot use a Dictionary because Keys are repeated. Moreover it will only return the first matching value?

`What happens to the rest?`

We can leave them. I am sending KeyValuePair created from a DataTable. I am creating that DataTable using `order by columnname` in its query.

Comment: May I ask why you can't use a Dictionary<TKey, TValue> instead?

Comment: @YngveB.Nilsen: Because Keys are repeated. Can you have a Dictionary where Keys are repeated?

Comment: That's what I thought.. But wont the Example in the answer be incomplete then? Since it will only return the first matching value? What happens to the rest?

Comment: Yes. We will have to leave them. I am sending KeyValuePair created from a DataTable. I am creating that DataTable using `order by columnname` in its query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just use a simple `foreach` loop?

---

**Example:**

```
public static bool TryGetValue<TKey, TValue>
(this KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] mapping, TKey key, out TValue value)
{
    foreach(var kvp in mapping)
        if (kvp.Key.Equals(key))
        {
            value = kvp.Value;
            return true;
        }

    value = default(TValue);
    return false;
}
```

---

Your implementation will throw an exception if the key doesn't exists due to `.First()`, and `FirstOrDefault()` would be ugly since `KeyValuePair` is a struct and hence you can't just compare it to `null`.

---

**Sidenote:**

Instead of extending `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[]`, you probably want to use `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` instead to be more flexible.

Comment: Unnecessary looping. Imagine a list with 1000s of mappings. Wouldn't this be a bit slow?

Comment: @BigYellowCactus: Point of SideNote taken. Thanks.

Comment: @YngveB.Nilsen Tell me more about how `ToLookup` works *without* looping over the entire array...

Comment: @YngveB.Nilsen Do some profiling/research to back your arguments. `ToLookup` will be *way more slower* than a simple loop. Not only does it loop over the entire array; for every element in this array, it calls some helper methods to extract the key for the element, determines the key, *iterates over its internal list of keys* it already encountered, adds that element to its approbiate `Grouping` instance, which in turn needs to be resized, etc. etc.

Comment: @BigYellowCactus: One line for your answer. "Brevity is the soul of wit" - [William Shakespeare Hamlet].